# Randomize url in meta tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iphone, web-applications, meta

I'm using the following meta tag to load a startup image for an iPhone web app:

```
<link href="apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

What I want to do is randomize the image path (01.png, 02.png, 03.png, etc.) when the page loads, e.g.:

```
<link href="random image path here" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
```

Anybody know how to do this with jQuery?

Comment: Look for Math.random()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab a random object from an array in javascript you can use:

```
var randomItem = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]
```

Combining this with your request you can do:

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){
        $(function(){
            var images = ['01.png', '02.png', '03.png'];
            $("[rel='apple-touch-startup-image']").attr("href", images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]);
        });
})(jQuery, this, document);
```